# How to find an ideal in a Lie subalgebra?

Tags: lie-algebras, ideals

Let's say $L$ is an Lie algebra and $H$ is an subalgebra.

It's very common to talk about the ideal generated by a subalgebra, i.e., the intersection of all ideals containing a subalgebra. That's look like an analoguos of the normal closure in group theory.

But what about an analoguos for the normal core? How can I find an ideal of $L$ that is contained in $H$? And what about the largest ideal that satisfies it?

Edit: maybe I wasn't accurate enough when I asked my question. I was asking about an analoguous for the normal core in the context of Lie algebras, i.e., a maximal ideal of $L$ with respect to the property of being contained in $H$.

Some responses involved the solvable radical, but I think that's not a good option, because algebras like the free Lie algebra with rank 2 or greater are not solvable and nor are any of their ideals (if I got it right).

Comment: Why not just take the sum of all ideals contained in $H$?

Comment: You need to formulate a little better. It is very easy to find an ideal in $H$. Do you want a minimal one that satisfies something? You can always take intersections and have some sort of "infimum ideal". Then you need to check if this infimum also satisfies the condition... making it, therefore, minimal. If the infimum does not satisfy... there is no minimal...

Comment: The intersection of all maximal ideals of a Lie algebra is the Jacobson radical ${\rm Jac}(L)=[L, {\rm rad}(L)]$, where ${\rm rad}(L)$ is the solvable radical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the sum of all ideals of $L$ that are contained in $H$. This will be the analogue of the normal core, i.e. the maximal ideal of $L$ contained in $H$.